How to view Image provided while creating Whatsapp message template
I loaded the available templates using Whatsapp Business api which provided the below given jason response:
{
"name": "test_template",
"components": [
{
"type": "HEADER",
"format": "IMAGE",
"example": {
"header_handle": [
"https://scontent.whatsapp.net/v/t61.29466-34/431629114_727445832925663_5828608310984645746_n.jpg?ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=8b1bef&_nc_ohc=HEd-nvn_anUAb5k8vBC&_nc_ht=scontent.whatsapp.net&edm=AH51TzQEAAAA&oh=01_ASDkfU6GazAFTOrZ87IWRqi9UQiYqUw-EIMDm05OQc2dsw&oe=6645DC3E"
]
}
},
{
"type": "BODY",
"text": "Hello {{1}},\n\nGet Flat 50% OFF on our Newly launched Lean mass Gainer\n\n{{2}} and {{3}}",
"example": {
"body_text": [
[
"Pintu",
"Till Today",
"Expires Soon"
]
]
}
},
{
"type": "FOOTER",
"text": "proquestnutrition.com"
},
{
"type": "BUTTONS",
"buttons": [
{
"type": "QUICK_REPLY",
"text": "Hello Sir"
},
{
"type": "URL",
"text": "Visit",
"url": "http://proquestnutrition.com/"
},
{
"type": "PHONE_NUMBER",
"text": "Call Now",
"phone_number": "+919354231262"
}
]
}
],
"language": "en_US",
"status": "APPROVED",
"category": "MARKETING",
"id": "727445829592330"
}

As it shows my Header format is Image and it contain header handle. Now how can I view the image i had provided to Facebook while creating this template or send template message.
I have tried getting the image my ways like providing the bearer token as authorization, etc. Please help
